# Browser prompt windows login when calling authorized webapi without permission

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, owin

I developed an aspnet webapi application witch exposes a set of authorized and unauthorized api methods.

I used OWIN middleware with application cookie based authorization and CORS enabled for all origins.

Calling authorized api without permission on localhost return 401 status code and that's ok.

The same request, perfomed on the server where the site application is deployed, let the browser show me a login form saying that "your connection to server is not private" and asking me for credentials; 401 status only returned when I press cancel button on the dialog.

I want to receive 401 status code with no browser dialog and no windows authentication...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to disable basic auth on server ISS